# voice over is enabled(UIaccesibility.isVoiceOverRunning) on parent A(nav controller) and On child view(UIactivityViewcontroller)voice over is disabled

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiaccessibility

I'm trying to achieving accessibility on activityviewcontroller. I'm presenting navigation controller over root view and later presenting activityviewcontroller over navigation controller.I found **UIaccesibility.isVoiceOverRunning is always false** before presenting activityviewcontroller.Even VoiceOver is working on parent.Any help is appreciated